# multiple event dates update to database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, datepicker

My scenario is that i have an events list and each event has multiple dates. Now I am using jquery multipledates plugin to load datepicker where i can select and unselect multiple dates. I can set as many dates as i want which i have already done. But Now the issue is when i have to unselect certain dates and set other dates (in case of events get postpone), whats the best way to deal with this situation.
My plan :-

Case 1 - Date exists in database and has been selected in datepicker - Do nothing.

Case 2 - Date doesnot exist in database and has not been selected in datepicker - Do nothing

Case 3 - Date doesnot exist in database and has been selected in datepicker - Add date to database.

Case 4 - Date exists in database and has not been selected in datepicker - Remove the date from database.

But I think this is going to kill server. Can anyone suggest better way of getting this done.

Event Dates table:
id - primary key,
event_id - foreign key,
date - DATE field,
last_modified - DATETIME field.

The date picker returns an array of date. And on submit the form sends this array to the controller and and i am using mysql insert statement for each array item. Each row is added if the date doesnt exist in table, if it is then update that row.

Comment: Are you able to provide some more details about how you are saving the dates, eg. the table structure in database - is each date saved in new row with event_id attached? And how are you sending all the selected dates back to the server after you update and save in UI - ie. as a single save once finished, or via ajax with each date add/change/remove ?

Comment: updated the question with the info you asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than worrying about the logic to check if the dates exist or have been changed, another approach would be to firstly remove all the dates with the current event_id and then add them all again as new entries, eg. firstly

```
DELETE FROM events_tbl where event_id='$event_id';
```

then just insert all the items from the array with a single INSERT statement. It doesn't appear from your table structure that you gain anything by keeping the existing entries, as you are not tracking the date/time they were first added, only when they were last updated - re-adding entries that have not changed is possibly less overhead than checking whether they need changing or not.

EDIT  - based on comment asking for approach if date added needs to be retained

If you do need to retain a date added field, but still want to have a minimum of calls to the database you could do it with just 3 calls by:

```
SELECT * from events_tbl WHERE event_id='$event_id';
```

Then put all the events in an associative array with the event date as the key and the date added as the value. Once you have this array, then:

```
DELETE FROM events_tbl where event_id='$event_id';
```

And then with the array of new events you can do something like:

```
foreach($new_dates as $date) {

    if (array_key_exists($date, $old_dates)) {
        $date_added = $old_dates[$date];
    } else {
        $date_added = $today;
    }
 }
```

But obviously in the above loop you would instead construct the parts for your single INSERT statement, some of which would have the current date for date_added, others would have the original date added from the array - hope that makes sense.

Glen

Comment: thats much nicer approach. what happens after a year there say there are more than 300 dates for a particular event. Doesnt that become a headache later?

Comment: I mean on a long run, doesnt this impact performance.

Comment: I am not sure how you would end up with hundreds of entries for an event with this approach as you delete all the entries for the given event each time you edit, so only ever have the current ones attached. With simple data like this, and if the relevant columns are indexed Mysql will cope with hundreds of thousands of entries anyway, unless you are on a cruddy low end server - another thing you may want to consider is a process to delete past dates if they are no longer relevant, that will keep the tables tidy as well.

Comment: just for curiosity, how would you do this if you want to save the created datetime and the modified datetime.

Comment: See my edit for option to retain date_added while still reducing database calls.